# Edited volume (humanities) for tenure?

Tags: publications, tenure-track, humanities, author-order

Does publishing an edited volume count for tenure (humanities)? And if so, does it count if you are 1st or 2nd editor in the same way?

Comment: Do you mean editing an existing volume or editor(s) of a new volume? Does the volume contain various papers of several authors or is it a monograph?

Comment: There is no standard.  It probably wouldn't be enough at Harvard.  You might not need to do any significant research for tenure at Southwest Northeast State University.  (I'm voting to close for depending on individual factors.)

Comment: Some humanities departments in some universities expect candidates for tenure to have published a book (and expect candidates for a full professorship to have published a second book). In such situations, I would not expect an edited volume to count as equivalent to a single-author book. There could be exceptions if the candidate can convince reviewers, deans, etc., that the editing was equivalent, in terms of amount of work and prestige, to writing a whole book.

Answer (score 6):

It is likely that it would, but whether it counts for a lot or a little, regardless of author order, depends on the institution and on who is judging the tenure portfolio.

And, it might depend on your meaning of "edited volume".

Comment: This is the kind of question that calls for asking senior colleagues out for lunch of coffee. Only they will be able to say what the culture in a department expects for tenure.